# the XGBoost model trained by 0.6a predict different result in 0.4a

Tags: xgboost

I trained a XGBoost model in one machine with 0.6a version, it predicted that the output has best result.

But when I download the model file and put it into another machine with XGBoost 0.4a30 version,the predicted result is much different. Because there is several model generated by 0.4a30 version, so I couldn't update the version.

I don't know how I can fix it. Is there some default parameter to be changed?